Can $\text{rank} (T) + \text{nullity} (T) = \dim V$ be proven with this simple argument?
I am helping one of my friends with linear algebra and gave him this theorem to prove as an exercise:
Theorem . Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over the field $F$ and let $T$ be
a linear transformation from $V$ into $W$. Suppose that $V$ is finite-dimensional.
Then  $\text{rank} (T) + \text{nullity} (T) = \dim V$.
He gave me this argument:
Any vector on $T(V)$ either came from the the set of vectors in $V$ that belongs to the nullity of $T$ or  came from the the set of vectors in $V$ that belongs to the rank of $T$. So that conclude that $\text{rank} (T) + \text{nullity} (T) = \dim V$. It is the same argument that every thing in the universe is in a (particular) box or outside of the box, and since all vectors come from the box $V$ then the dimension should still be the same.
I am convinced that this is wrong but the question is where exactly does the error came from in this argument?

"Any vector on $T(V)$ either came from the the set of vectors in $V$ that belongs to the nullity of $T$ or came from the the set of vectors in $V$ that belongs to the rank of $T$": for one thing, rank and nullity are numbers, therefore it's a bit of a mystery what "the set of vectors that belongs to" one of those numbers is. If we assume that they mean that for all $v\in T(V)$ there is some $x$ such that $x\in \ker T$ or $x\in \operatorname{range}T$, and $T(x)=v$, then this is false already. Namely, it's possible that ${0}\subsetneq\operatorname{range}(T^2)\subsetneq \operatorname{range}T$.

The quote "Came from the set of vectors in V that belongs to the rank of T" doesn't really make sense to me. As stated above, rank and nullity are numbers, not subspaces. I think you are meaning to talk about the kernel and the image of the transformation. However,  the image is also a subspace of W, not V, so it could be the possibility that no vectors in V belong to the image of T, so it is not exactly clear what is meant.

I can only guess what your friend means. Maybe he’s trying to say $V \cong \ker(T) \oplus T(V)$, which would be correct, but it’s proving this that’s the important part. If one is sufficiently familiar with all the concepts, sure, they can internally understand the theorem in this way. But based on your friend’s description (which is far from accurate), I don’t think he really understands it.


Any vector on $T(V)$ either came from the set of vectors in $V$ that belongs to the nullity of $T$ or came from the the set of vectors in $V$ that belongs to the rank of $T$.

First of all, "belongs to the nullity of $T$" or "belongs to the rank of $T$" do not make sense. I assume your friend means

Any vector on $T(V)$ either came from the set of vectors in $V$ that belongs to the null space of $T$ or came from the the set of vectors in $V$ that belongs to the image space of $T$.

Even then, this is wrong. Every vector in $T(V)$ is by definition in the image space of $T$. So, even if we try to salvage out the following that might be what your friend meant:

Any vector on $V$ either came from the set of vectors in $V$ that belongs to the null space of $T$ or came from the the set of vectors in $V$ that belongs to the image space of $T$.

Not true either since the image space of $T$ is a subset of $W$, not $V$. None of the three interpretations I could come up with are correct, maybe the friend actually has a correct idea, but they need to be more clear on what they mean.
Hope this helps  :)
